# Fetch entries filtered by array within custom field

Tags: entries

I'm using the [multidate field](https://github.com/bjerenec/craftcms-multidatefield) plugin, which is excellent at presenting dates but I need to return entries based on testing the first date in there. I typically test with the entries loop, like so:

```
{% if product.dates.dates[0] | date('U') > now | date ('U') %}
```

but would prefer to only get entries fitting that criteria in the first place. Is there any way to fetch entries according to the first value in a an array like this?

```
{% set products = craft.commerce.products.dates(somehow only test the first value in the dates array here) %}
```

The field looks something like this:

```
dates [ // this is the custom field name
    dates [ // this is the dates array within the custom field
        [0] // this is the date object I want to test against
        [1]
        [2]
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That plugin doesn't provide a custom element type, so there's no way for it to have a chance to modify the main elements query when fetching the data.

In its existing form, you'll have to do the filtering on the Twig side like you're doing to grab the one you're looking for.

Comment: I feared that was the case. No worries.